# .JS hoverbox not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a site design that requires a hoverbox on mouseover, the hover box will display html with a brief description of the page content and a link. I came across this Fiddle which seamed easy enough

http://jsfiddle.net/U7tRy/57/

However for the life in me I cannot get it to work

I have put my code JS code below and in Fiddle and would very much appreciate if the community could help me.

```
    $('.hovercard').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).show();
}, function() {
    $('.hovercard').hide();
});
$('.about-us-card ').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hovercard').delay(100).fadeIn('linear'); // show() doesn't seem to work with delay
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.hovercard').delay(100).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpt3pu9h/

Comment: First problem that I see is that you did not include the jQuery plugin in jsFiddle. You can do that in the left panel > first dropdown.

Comment: @Spokey thanks, but even with jQuery 2.1.0 loaded it does not work.

Comment: Works for me in chrome. Unfortunatly the formatting is wrong and makes the hover function not work properly. http://jsfiddle.net/dpt3pu9h/3/ You may need to change the CSS to work with your new function. If you need further help with this please create a new question explaining your problem with the function and not edit this one